# Timthumb Not Working

Tags: wordpress, bluehost, timthumb

For some reason, timthumb isn't working on my site.  I've tried all the chmod stuff, edited my htaccess to include what it needs, and it STILL isn't working.

The site is here:

69.89.31.103/~infoconc/

The host is bluehost, who I've never worked with.  Not my choice.

Need help!  Thanks!

Comment: is GD library installed ?? This can help you to check requriments [http://www.der-prinz.com/images-displaying-solving-issues-timthumb/]

Comment: Yup - here's my php

http://69.89.31.103/~infoconc/gdlibrary.php

Comment: If possible, avoid TimThumb, alternatives: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/21634/12615

Answer (score 0):

I see your timthumb give this error: `[an error occurred while processing this directive]`

So, try this:

```
- Go to cPanel
- Open File Manager from Files section
- Navigate to domain folder
- Check "Perms" column on far right hand side
- Files should be set to: 0644 (this is the UNIX file permissions)
- Folders should be set to: 0755
```

From [bluehostforum](http://www.bluehostforum.com/showthread.php?32117-an-error-occurred-while-processing-this-directive&p=102341#post102341) and not tested by me!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the GD Library is missing. You can fix it by installing and restarting Apache then checking your file permission.

---

**Step 1) Install GD Library**

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-gd
```

**Step 2) Restart Apache2**

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```